# how to convert date value through jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm getting below value for a datepicker control in Jquery,

**Mon May 9 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2011**

Now I need to convert the above value to below string **"5/9/2011"**.

Please help....

Comment: Do you use the jqueryUI datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a jQuery issue - see the [Javascript Date Object documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```
var d = new Date('Mon May 9 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2011');
var d_formatted = d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `Date` object from the text with `new Date`, then simply make a string using the methods on the `Date` object, i.e.:

```
var date = new Date(someDate);
var str = date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Looking at the format of your date, it is probably already a `Date` object that is being represented as a string, so invoking the appropriate methods on it (second line) will give you the representation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' });
```